# Entity Framework Many to Many and Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 with MySql and having a problem with the eager loading of a many to many relationship. A simplified version of the affected tables looks like:

```
CabinCategory - CabinCategoryId
CabinGrade - CabinGradeId, CabinCategoryId
Deck - DeckId
DeckCabinGrades - DeckId, CabinGradeId <--- Join table
```

I'm ultimately trying to access CabinCategory.CabinGrade.Deck

I think I've managed to map this successfully using

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CabinGrade>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Decks)
            .WithMany(d => d.CabinGrades)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("CabinGradeId");
                    m.MapRightKey("DeckId");
                    m.ToTable("DeckCabinGrades");
                }
            );
```

If I eager load CabinGrades but let Decks lazy load everything is great. However, if I attempt to eager load CabinGrades and Decks with

```
this.Context.CabinCategories.Include("CabinGrades").Include("CabinGrades.Decks").ToList();
```

I get a null refference exception and the following stack trace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity) +57
System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntityToCollectionOrReference(MergeOption mergeOption, IEntityWrapper wrappedSource, AssociationEndMember sourceMember, IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, AssociationEndMember targetMember, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean inKeyEntryPromotion) +683
System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.UpdateRelationships(ObjectContext context, MergeOption mergeOption, AssociationSet associationSet, AssociationEndMember sourceMember, EntityKey sourceKey, IEntityWrapper wrappedSource, AssociationEndMember targetMember, IList targets, Boolean setIsLoaded) +797
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.FullSpanAction(IEntityWrapper wrappedSource, IList`1 spannedEntities, AssociationEndMember targetMember) +367
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.<>c__DisplayClass2`2.<HandleFullSpanCollection>b__0(Shaper state, List`1 spannedEntities) +38
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ResetCollection(Shaper shaper) +193
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext() +251
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement() +31
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.ReadElement() +40
System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext() +51
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +471
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +79
```

When I check out the MySql query log it's actually generated a query that works fine and gets the Decks. It's as though it can't convert the results back into objects.

Am I asking to much of EF eager loading or should this work? Could it be a MySql connector problem?

**EDIT**: It works fine when it's only one 'level' deep (CabinGrade.Decks). The problem seems to occur when it's two 'levels' deep  (CabinCategory.CabinGrade.Decks)

Comment: It should work and it could be a MySql Connector problem, yes. You could make two experiments: 1) Remove `Include("CabinGrades")`. It's not necessary because to load `CabinGrades.Decks`, the `CabinGrades` must be loaded anyway. 2) Try the strongly typed syntax: `Include(c => c.CabinGrades.Select(cg => cg.Decks))`. Just a bit trial and error. And perhaps it might be helpful if you show your entity classes with navigation properties in detail.

Comment: Thanks @Slauma. I finally figured it out, although it's not a total solution...

If the mapping table (DeckCabinGrades) has no entry for a given CabinGradeId it's trying to instantiate a Deck from a load of nulls.

If I make sure there is a mapping table entry or every CabinGrade I'm selecting out, it works ok. 

This seems like a flaw with either EF or MySql Connector, especially given that it works one level deep (CabinGrade.Decks) but not two levels deep (CabinCategory.CabinGrade.Decks).

Comment: Oh, this sounds like a serious bug. I've just tested such a model with EF and SQL Server (basically with a single `CabinCategory` in DB, a single `CabinGrade` refering to that category and with no `Decks` (empty join table)) and your query works, I get just an empty `Decks` collection in the loaded `CabinCategory.CabinGrade`. We must suspect the MySQL Connector.

Comment: @Slauma .. Yes, I just tried DevArt dotConnect MySql and it works. So it's a certainly a MySql Connector bug. I'll log it with them

Comment: You could post your findings as an answer and accept your own answer, just to finish this question. No other answer to expect here anymore, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems this is a bug with MySql .NET Cconnector 6.4.4 (see comments)

This has been logged with MySql

Comment: @TravisJ I've since stopped using MySql .NET Connector, so I can't be sure if it's fixed or not.

I logged the bug here. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62670 . Unfortunately I just didn't have time to follow up with example tables and data as they were asking. If you're still experiencing this with the latest version, you could resurrect the bug and add some test data.

Comment: Sorry to pry, but did you end up going with a different connector? Or did you just stop using mysql?

Comment: @TravisJ No problem. I bought Devart dotConnect Mysql Pro as I needed to get around this problem without switching to Sql Server. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/ It handles this fine and certainly (as of a year ago) had better support for Entity Framework. That may have changed with the current release of MysqlConnector for Oracle, but if you're still experiencing the bug then I guess not.