# Entity Framework Code First using MySql - Map(a => a.ToTable() not creating specified table name

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am trying to get EF Code First working with MySql 5.5.19 (Connector/Net 6.4.4) but when the database is created, it is ignoring the `Map(a => a.ToTable()` command for a join table.

```
HasMany(t => t.AllowedAssociations).WithMany()
 .Map(a => a.ToTable("AllowedTemplateAssociations")
 .MapLeftKey("TemplateId")
 .MapRightKey("AllowedAssociationToId"));
```

MySql is throwing an error that there is no table called "templatetemplate" - somewhere along the line the name I have specified has been ignore and "templatetemplate" is expected. (NOTE: if I change my code to `ToTable("templatetemplate")` it works as expected)

My model:

```
public class Template
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Template> AllowedAssociations { get; set; }
}
```

My config:

```
public class TemplateConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AssetTracking.Domain.Entities.Template>
{
    public TemplateConfiguration()
    {
        Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
        HasMany(t => t.AllowedAssociations).WithMany()
           .Map(a => a.ToTable("AllowedTemplateAssociations")
           .MapLeftKey("TemplateId").MapRightKey("AllowedAssociationToId"));}
}
```

This works as expected if I use SQLSERVER, the table is named correctly.

Any ideas? Have I forgotten a config anywhere?

(I have `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();` set)

Comment: It would not be the first bug in the MySQL connector for EF. It looks like the join table name mapping is simply ignored (or not implemented?) and the default name with removed pluralization (which is `templatetemplate`) is used despite of other mapping. Here was another bug with many-to-many relationships: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7712620/270591.

Comment: @Slauma thanks for the reply - i suspected it might be a bug in the provider but wanted to check i hadn't missed out a config setting somewhere. thanks